# 401 error on custom fonts on webpage

Tags: iis, truetype, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to include custom fonts on my webpage. I have downloaded the files and am correctly referencing the font file in my css. The fonts still fail to load, so I checked firebug and noticed that I am getting a HTTP Error "401.3 Unauthorized" for the .TTF.

I checked in IIS, and TTF is an accepted MIME type. Not sure where else to look or what do to next to debug this.

I don't have enough reputation to post images, but I can post some code. I'm assuming that since it's a 401, it has no problem locating the file, just accessing it.

```
<style>
     @font-face {
     font-family: 'Lato';
     src: url('Lato-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'); 
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with my actual font file was encrypted, which meant it must be related to the way I extracted it from a ZIP. The file name was green too, which should've triggered to me that it was a encrypted.